# C# Visual Studio if文のフォーマット方法

Tags: c#, visual-studio

タイトルの件、if文のフォーマットを以下のようにしたいと考えております。

例えばVisual Studioのフォーマット機能を使うなどして
なるべく簡単に変換する方法はありませんでしょうか？

用はif文の処理が1文であっても、かならず中括弧を使うようにして欲しいのです。

ご検討よろしくお願い致します。

変更前のif文

```
if(var == 0) return;
```

変更後のif文

```
if(var == 0)
{
     return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio のバージョンによっては、ifに点線で下線が引かれます。カーソルを合わせると、右端に電球アイコンが出るので、クリックして「波かっこを追加します」。
あるいは、拡張機能の「AStyle Extension」を追加。

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio 2019では[コードのクリーンアップ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/ide/whats-new-visual-studio-2019?view=vs-2019#code-cleanup)が強化されています。

[コードのスタイル設定](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/ide/code-styles-and-code-cleanup?view=vs-2019)にまとめられていますが、[[オプション] ダイアログ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/ide/code-styles-and-code-cleanup?view=vs-2019#code-styles-in-the-options-dialog-box)で詳細な書式設定が可能です。この機能自体はインテリセンスで変更が提案されるまでとなります。
その上で、[コード スタイルの適用](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/ide/code-styles-and-code-cleanup?view=vs-2019#apply-code-styles)を実行すると、選択した書式設定について一括して適用されます。

両機能を組み合わせることで`if`文の書式も統一することができます。

Answer (score 2):

ちなみに「AStyle Extension」は今 2種類あります。
まあ使っているVisualStudioの版数に合わせて検索されるでしょうから、迷わないと思いますが。

[AStyle Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Lukamicoder.AStyleExtension) : VS2010-VS2015,AVR Studio5,Atmel Studio6-7
[AStyle Extension 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Lukamicoder.AStyleExtension2017) : VS2017

VS2019用の拡張機能にはまだ掲載されていないようです。VS2017用をダウンロードして入れてみるか、単独で動作するコマンドを外部ツールとして自分で組み込むかすれば出来るでしょう。

で、ご要望の使い方に相当するオプションは以下の2つの組み合わせになるでしょう。
ただし、2つ目の`--add-braces`は、上記Extensionの中では **--add-brackets** になっているので注意してください。

[--style=allman / --style=bsd / --style=break / -A1](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_style=allman)

> ```
> int Foo(bool isBar)
> {
>     if (isBar)
>     {
>         bar();
>         return 1;
>     }
>     else
>         return 0;
> }
> ```

[--add-braces / -j](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/astyle.html#_add-braces)

> ```
> if (isFoo)
>     isFoo = false;
> ```
>
> becomes:
>
> ```
> if (isFoo) {
>     isFoo = false;
> }
> ```

その他の指定については、以下のような記事もあるので、参考にしてください。
[C#のコードフォーマット設定を共有する方法](https://qiita.com/hakuta/items/29c988181d40829b1679)

以下は単独で動作するコマンド本体のページです。
[Artistic Style 3.1](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/)
[Artistic Style Developer Information - Calling Artistic Style from a C# Program](http://astyle.sourceforge.net/develop/sharp.html)